# Is there a way to make css underline by every line?

Tags: css

I'm making hexo blog theme. I'am trying to make line note like style. I want to make css on each line has underline(not like U tag)

want

[image: want]

But if I use `border-bottom: 1px solid grey`

real

[image: real]

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: You can mix it very well. i updated my answer, too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72067345/14807111

Answer (score 3):

You may also use a gradient to draw a grid below your text.
It has to match the line-height

Here an example with CSS var() to ease the tuning.

```css
p, textarea {
  --lineH: 1.6em;
  line-height: var(--lineH);
  padding:var(--lineH);
  padding-block:0;/*reset to set first line right at top */
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0 1.4em, gray 1.4em calc(1.4em + 2px), transparent calc(1.4em + 2px) 1.6em)  50% 0 / calc(100% - var(--lineH) * 2  ) 100% no-repeat ;

}
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
<textarea placeholder="Type your texts here"></textarea>
```

Added a textarea to the example to show another possible use.

---

ressources if you need them

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/gradient/repeating-linear-gradient

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-calc-in-css/

---

you can use more gradients to mimic a full note sheet https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bGLGNWB

Comment: This answer is great for one reason [See HERE](https://i.ibb.co/ryq12g6/image.png)

Comment: you can simplify the gradient to only `repeating-linear-gradient(transparent 0 calc(1.6em - 2px), gray 0  1.6em)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **text-decoration: underline** to get that effect (although the **text-underline-offset** style rule which is used to space the line from thee normal position is NOT supported in IE at all and some other browsers are a bit spotty with it). The only other way to do it is to split the content into spans and apply the border bottom or ::after pseudo-element to each span.

```css
p { 
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: 400;
   line-height: 32px;
   text-decoration: underline;
   text-underline-offset: 4px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hello world<h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed mauris a metus ultricies sagittis commodo sed tellus. Cras sodales nunc ut neque feugiat dignissim. Nullam ligula mauris, blandit eu dignissim at, rutrum vitae nisi. Proin facilisis massa vel elit fermentum, sit amet aliquam quam hendrerit. Aenean interdum nisi a metus consequat, vitae viverra ligula scelerisque. Sed in erat dictum, dapibus arcu quis, interdum orci. Suspendisse sit amet gravida purus, eu facilisis felis. Aliquam consectetur dapibus augue a suscipit. In semper pretium erat. Duis eget sollicitudin arcu, volutpat scelerisque est. Proin nisl nisi, tincidunt a justo id, lobortis tempor lacus. Quisque eu tincidunt ex.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The p tag is a block element. Means if you assign a border the border would be assigned for the block. If you change p tag to an inline element then the border would be displayed like you want.

#### Update

**with inside underlined words**

```css
p {
  display: inline;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

p span {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hello world<h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span>consectetur adipiscing</span> elit. Duis sed mauris a metus ultricies sagittis commodo sed tellus. Cras sodales nunc ut neque feugiat dignissim. Nullam ligula mauris, blandit eu dignissim at, rutrum vitae nisi. Proin facilisis massa vel elit fermentum, sit amet aliquam quam hendrerit. Aenean interdum nisi a metus consequat, vitae viverra ligula scelerisque. Sed in erat dictum, dapibus arcu quis, interdum orci. Suspendisse sit amet gravida purus, eu facilisis felis. Aliquam consectetur dapibus augue a suscipit. In semper pretium erat. Duis eget sollicitudin arcu, volutpat scelerisque est. Proin nisl nisi, tincidunt a justo id, lobortis tempor lacus. Quisque eu tincidunt ex.</p>
```

```css
p {
  display: inline;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hello world<h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed mauris a metus ultricies sagittis commodo sed tellus. Cras sodales nunc ut neque feugiat dignissim. Nullam ligula mauris, blandit eu dignissim at, rutrum vitae nisi. Proin facilisis massa vel elit fermentum, sit amet aliquam quam hendrerit. Aenean interdum nisi a metus consequat, vitae viverra ligula scelerisque. Sed in erat dictum, dapibus arcu quis, interdum orci. Suspendisse sit amet gravida purus, eu facilisis felis. Aliquam consectetur dapibus augue a suscipit. In semper pretium erat. Duis eget sollicitudin arcu, volutpat scelerisque est. Proin nisl nisi, tincidunt a justo id, lobortis tempor lacus. Quisque eu tincidunt ex.</p>
```

Comment: This is what i wanted

Comment: @YellowBird Thank you for feedback and you welcome! If you found that my answer solved your problem, it would be nice if you mark this answer as accepted. Merci!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```css
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset:6px;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the text-decoration-line property.
text-decoration-line: underline;

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-decoration-line